# Automate appending additional database connection to env.php

Tags: magento2, database, installation

I have a customized **env.php** that has an additional customized **database** connection appended to it. This file is edited manually and is not in a source code repo because a new installation of Magento will overwrite it.

My objective is to ensure the customized **env.php** file is in place after every deployment regardless if it's a new Magento install or update.

What is the most secure and efficient approach to appending this extra db connection to **env.php** during every run of the deployment script (this script is in **source code repo**)?

I want to be careful not to interfere with the way Magento handles the **env.php** so the correct Magento commands and timing of the data being appended is key.

Thank you